# MySQL insert data from other table

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database, sql-insert

This question is similar to my previous question except this is INSERT instead of update
I have two tables: contacts and companies.

```
contacts has : id, group_id, company_id, email, company
companies has: id, group_id, name, email
```

so using this query

```
UPDATE contacts c
INNER JOIN companies co ON c.company_id = co.id 
SET c.group_id = co.group_id,
    c.company = companies.name
```

I can move update data from company to contacts where there contact.company_id = company.id.

But how can I do INSERT instead for all the company where does not have contact yet? or to make things simpler, how can I move all companies table data into contacts table data. e.g:

```
Companies
id   group_id   name   email
1    1          abc    a@a.com
2    1          def    d@d.com
3    1          ghi    g@g.com

Contacts
id   group_id   company_id   email     company   phone
1    1          1            a@a.com   abc
2    1          2            d@d.com   def
3    1          3            g@g.com   ghi
```

So I would like the entry like that, and for the one that is no value will be default to NULL or None

Comment: Do you have a Primary Key set? Have you looked at `INSERT IGNORE`?

Comment: @DevlshOne well primary key is set to id on both table. basicly due to spec changes, the project will not use Companies table anymore, and I need to migrate all data from company and treat it as contacts instead. How should I do with INSERT IGNORE? could you show me the query?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you want:

```sql
INSERT INTO Contacts (id,group_id,company_id,email,name)
SELECT co.id,co.group_id,co.id,co.email,co.name
FROM company co
LEFT JOIN contacts c ON co.id = c.company_id
WHERE c.company_id IS NULL
```

This will insert all the information from contacts in company that wasn't already there. the column phone will be left null, since there is no information in contacts for that column.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you would need to do an outer join between the 2 tables in your select statement then look for a field in your destination table to be null and only select those rows.

```
insert into t1 (f1,f2,f3) select s1,s2,s3 from sourcetable as st 
  left outer join t1 on 
      t1.f1=st.s1,
      t1.f2=st.s2,
      t1.f3=st.s3
  where t1.id is null;
```

This way you only get the rows from st where there is no id in t1.